# Nginx Redirect for Specific URL

Tags: nginx, redirect

For our site's server block in nginx, I have these location directives:

`location ~*  ^.+\.(ico|css|js|eot|woff|otf|svg|gif|jpe?g|png|swg|woff2)(\?[a-z0-9=_]+)?$`

`location /applications/`

`location /`

`location ~ \.php$`

I have a specific URL from our old forum software that I want to redirect. The URL looks like this:

https://www.example.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?f=105

So far, nothing I've tried seems to match this URL. I have tried a few different rewrite statements in the / location and I've also tried an exact match thinking that the longest match should win:

```
location = /forums/forumdisplay.php?f=105 {
    return 301 https://newurl;
}
```

This doesn't work - I still get a 404 from this URL. Where/how should I do this redirect?

Comment: The `?f=105` is not part of the normalised URI used to match `location` statements. Try: `if ($request_uri = "/forums/forumdisplay.php?f=105") { return 301 https://newurl; }`

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I created a location just for /forums/forumdisplay.php and then used the if block inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use:

```
location = /forums/forumdisplay.php {
    if ($arg_f = 105) {
        return 301 https://newurl;
    }
    fastcgi_pass /path/to/php.sock; # Send the request to PHP processor
}
```

This approach will match the `/forums/forumdisplay.php` URL where the `f` query argument is set to 105, and there can be additional query arguments.

The example in comment requires an exact match to the full URL, and doesn't work if URL happens to be

```
http://example.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?f=105&fbclid=4567
```

Comment: There was one important step missing here, that is, processing of requests where `f` query argument is not set. One has to ensure those requests are handled properly. What "properly" is, depends on the other configuration.